# Why the position:absolute is conflict with -webkit-transform / transform/ -ms-transform

Tags: jquery, html, css, absolutelayout

Here is my website:
http://rsvp.com.hk/tmp_web/

What I would like to achieve is resize the whole site to 67% and align it to top. If you open the developer mode , there is a "container" class, I have specific the

```
transform:scale(0.67,0.67);
-ms-transform:scale(0.67,0.67); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:scale(0.67,0.67); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

on it, then the absolute item is not "fix" on the screen , that means, without transform ,  when I resize the browser window, the text,and the image do not move along with the screen, but after using transform , it will. How to fix this?

Also, how to align the "container" to the top? Thanks for helping

Comment: That is a horrible way to try and scale a page...there **must** be better options.

Comment: Dude use margin-left and margin-top instead.

Comment: Your entire methodology in achieving what you are trying to do here is more or less semantically bad.  You should investigate what it is you want to achieve and devise a different solution.

Comment: I initially do it by fixing the website in 1900px width, and now I have to fix it at 1900px * 0.67 , and I am finding a easy way to achieve it